# why the 'if' statement is executetd even though the condition is False (from what I see)?

Tags: python-3.x

this is a problem set from edx python programming.
It has one bug I cannot figure out.
Basically, the logic is if the secretword is equal to a guessword, then, bump up the count.
In the case below, I intentionally put an empty list to test the code. during the first run, it's clear that [''] is not equal to 'a', but the code still execute the if statement.
Am I missing something?
Thank you.

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
'''
secretWord: string, the word the user is guessing
lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
returns: boolean, True if all the letters of secretWord are in lettersGuessed;
  False otherwise
'''
count = 0
tempList = []
for element in lettersGuessed:
    if element in secretWord and element not in tempList: #to avoid re-counting repetitive char that matches with string
        count += 1
        tempList.append(element)
if count == len(secretWord):
    return True
else:
    return False


print(isWordGuessed('a',['']))
```

Comment: The function body is not indented. How is your code indented exactly? Perhaps that is already the cause of the problem.

Comment: You list is not empty, it contains the empty string `''` which is contained in every string. This makes your counter incrément on the first iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why in your case `if` is `True`

Your `if` statement is evaluated to `True` because `'' in 'put_any_string_here'` is always `True`

Meaning that **empty strings are always sub-strings of other strings**

## Edit

- I didn't find a bug in your code. But here's a refactor since you want to revise the code. You can use [Lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)
- Make sure you follow [Python's style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for naming your variables

---

```
def is_word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    l = list(filter(lambda c: c in letters_guessed, list(secret_word)))
    return ''.join(l) == secret_word
```

Comment: Ahh, Thank you very much, learned new thing today..Is there a better way to revise this code?

Comment: My pleasure. And yes I'm editing my answer to solve the actual bug as we speak